# Can I add a map as an attribute of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, insert, attributes, maps

I'm creating a program with C++ that rates Elden Ring bosses. I'd like to add a map as an attribute of my parent boss class. Here's what I'm trying:

```
class Boss {
public:
    string name;
    string type;
    int hp;
    bool parriable;
    bool breakPoise;
    string damageTypeDealt;
    map< string, int > absorptions;
    map< string, int > resistances;}
```

When I attempt to create an instance of that class:

```
// BOSS OBJECTS
Boss godrickTheGrafted(
    "Godrick the Grafted", 
    "Legend Boss", 
    6080, 
    false, 
    true,
    "Standard Damage, Fire Damage",
    absorptions.insert(pair<string, int>("Phy (Standard)", 0)),
    resistances.insert(pair<string, int>("Not yet", 0))
    );
```

I get an error under each map insert saying "identifier not defined". I'm declaring the class before my main class currently. Can I even do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes you can have a data member of  type `std::map`  in a class.

Comment: You wouldn't write `damageTypeDealt.insert("Standard Damage, Fire Damage")` there to initialize `damageTypeDealt`. So why do you think the `absorptions.insert` and `resistances.insert` belong there?

Comment: The `class Boss` declaration is correct, but the `Boss godrickTheGrafted(...` declaration is totally wrong. Anyway, post a [mcve]

Comment: `absorptions.insert(pair<string, int>("Phy (Standard)", 0))` -> `{{"Phy (Standard)", 0}}`. Equivalently for `resistances`.

Comment: `absorptions` and `resistances` are indeed not defined. Presumably you are trying to access member data in a call to a constructor, which you cannot do.

Comment: By the way: Strings to identify types is not a good idea, this is always prone to typos. Better: Use enums instead: `type`, keys of the maps, and for the damage type dealt, if multiple ones are possible, either a `std::vector` or integer flags OR-ed together (enum needs to be appropriately defined then). If you later on need the names for the enum members then have a function returning them if need be (and possibly an `operator>>` for streams, if using them). A single string for the multiple damage types is even less appropriate if you need to extract a single one as requiring string parsing.

Comment: An exception might be if you *always* only need the texts anyway (for printing them out to the user) and *never* do evaluate them otherwise – then you should work with pre-defined string *constants*, though, not literals again and again – and the class members *might* even be *references* to const then (`std::string const& type` – apart from the name, of course, as presumably unique anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a data member of type `std::map` in a class. But the syntax you're using to create an object of `Boss` is wrong in that you're trying to use `insert` on the parameter.

You can solve this as follows.

```
int main()
{
     // BOSS OBJECT
     Boss godrickTheGrafted("Godrick the Grafted", "Legend Boss", 
    6080, 
    false, 
    true,
    "Standard Damage, Fire Damage",
//--vv-------------------vv-------------->note the added braces
    {{"Phy (Standard)", 0}},
    {{"Not yet", 0}});
     
}
```

[Working Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/LYRNiIT47)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* have maps just like strings or any other container/structure from standard library. Your call to the constructor is not correct, though:

```
Boss godrickTheGrafted
(
    "Godrick the Grafted", 
    "Legend Boss", 
    6080, 
    false, 
    true,
    "Standard Damage, Fire Damage",
    absorptions.insert(pair<string, int>("Phy (Standard)", 0)), // <-- !!!
    resistances.insert(pair<string, int>("Not yet", 0))         // <-- !!!

);
```

You cannot call `insert` on a member (that actually at this point even doesn't exist yet) to create a function parameter to fill data with.

You can call `insert` *afterwards*:

```
Boss godrickTheGrafted
(
    "Godrick the Grafted", 
    "Legend Boss", 
    6080, 
    false, 
    true,
    "Standard Damage, Fire Damage"
);

godrickTheGrafted.absorptions.insert(pair<string, int>("Phy (Standard)", 0));
godrickTheGrafted.resistances.insert(pair<string, int>("Not yet", 0));
```

provided the maps are public as in your example.

Alternatively you can have maps in the constructor you can create them on the fly as:

```
Boss godrickTheGrafted
(
    "Godrick the Grafted", 
    "Legend Boss", 
    6080, 
    false, 
    true,
    "Standard Damage, Fire Damage",
    { pair<string, int>("Phy (Standard)", 0) },
    { pair<string, int>("Not yet", 0) }

    // or simpler just
    //{ { "Phy (Standard)", 0 } },
    //{ { "Not yet", 0 } }
);
```

if your constructor contains two parameters of type `std::map`.

Comment: This is literally exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!